# Turtle Beach X12 HeadSet Mic Not Working?

Tags: sound, microphone, headset

I did a lot of research, I had not luck.

I can hear audio in my headset, but the mic is not detected.

Here is my set up:

- Ubuntu 12.04 (64-BIT/x64) LTS
- Intel Celeron Processor (Dual-core)
- Realtek Soundcard (Unknown model, came with the laptop I am using)
- 8 GB Ram
- Dual-booted with Windows 7 Home Premium (64-BIT/x64)

My head set is a Turtle Beach EARFORCE X12.

Here is how my headset is set up:

- Mic-In: Mic Jack
- Audio-Out: Headset Jack
- USB: For power

I am not using any driver, because Turtle Beach does not require a driver. I have the mic working on Windows 7, so it is definitely not my PC, it is the OS.

I am not sure how to fix it, since in my search, the questions on sites were not answered/not my situation.

I have specified all the details that I know about the system that other posts that were abandoned/not answered/locked.

I have been working to make my mic work for hours with no success, and my other headset (A Logitech) works just fine, but my Mic is using the input on my laptop, so it should be detected but isn't.

Anyone have a solution/work-around/diagnostic advice? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: you have to turn on mute mic on the xbox 360 amp. and ur mic will work for your linux and PC

Comment: Also check the mute mic is turned off on the headphones cord.

Answer (score 1):

change the settings option in Sound Preferences > Hardware to Input+Output.